# NSPredicate: Search on NSNumber (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate, nsnumber

I  have an Cocoa Core-Date Application. I added a search field and bound it. Now, I have tried to add some predicates but failed! Here are my two questions:

First, the predicate should filter NSNumbers but I cannot build a working predicate. My try:

```
keyPath == [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[$value integerValue]]
```

(keyPath represents a NSNumber which stores an integer.)

Second, I want to have a predicate which searches in two attributes. The first attribute is firstName and the other lastName. So, if the user types "John Appleseed" he gets an result but with my tries I only get firstName or lastName.

Thanks for your help, if there are any questions ask them. I dont know if I described my problem detailed enough ;-)

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) `keypath==$value`

(2) `firstName==$firstNameVar && lastName==$lastNameVar`

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't construct NSNumber in predicate, compare to $value directly.
2. Predicates can be combined to make a complex predicate. You can either build it in code or use logic operators (or, ||, and , &&) to build a complex predicate with format.

Apple's documentation has enough samples of predicates using, read it: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html